# How to get fixed IP address of openstack instance using novaclient

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova, novaclient

I spin-up openstack instances using noveclient python api

```
server = nova.servers.create(name ="xxx",password="xxx",image="xxx",flavor= flavor.id ,key_name = "adikarikey",nics = [{'net-id': 'xxx','v4-fixed-ip': ''}])
```

I want to get the IP address of the created instance. How can  I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, not sure if it is the most efficient, but this works for me on Rackspace cloud servers. Note that because spinning up a server is an asynchronous task it is necessary to wait for the server to be operational before extracting the IP address.

```
ip_address = None
for network in server.networks['public']:
    if re.match('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', network):
        ip_address = network
        break
if ip_address is None:
    print 'No IP address assigned!'
    sys.exit(1)
print 'The server is waiting at IP address {0}.'.format(ip_address)
```

This example is part of an article I wrote on the `nova` APIs, as supported by Rackspace. The full article is [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-rackspace-cloud-api).